# Linux a long shell command with pipe operation

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, tar

This is my command.

`ssh username@hostname "cd /usr ; echo \"password\" | sudo -S tar cpf - . --ignore-failed-read" | tar xpf - -C /usr`

The problem is that the latter tar command needs `sudo`, so if I change my code like 
`ssh username@hostname "cd /usr ; echo \"password\" | sudo -S tar cpf - . --ignore-failed-read" | sudo tar xpf - -C /usr`。But I want to run it automatically, this case is not what I want.

If I change command to

`ssh username@hostname "cd /usr ; echo \"password\" | sudo -S tar cpf - . --ignore-failed-read" | echo "password" | sudo -S tar xpf - -C /usr`。In this case I can not get the former tar data flow。

So how can I simultaneously get the former tar data flow and give `sudo` to my latter tar command?

PS: I don't want to create actual tar file。I want it compress and uncompress on the fly.

Anyone can help me? Thank you very much~!

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about how to configure sudo so that it does not require a password.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468416/setting-up-passwordless-sudo-on-linux-distributions

Comment: But actually i have no access to  configure sudo so that it does not require a password

Comment: Probably a better question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Unpack without `sudo` and then perform a `sudo cp -r` to place it where it needs to be.

Comment: Sounds good, but what if the file are too much，and the disk is too small to   place the new files. What i want is to override the existing files.

Comment: @PengWu You appear to have the root password, which is all you need to configure `sudo`.

Comment: Can you replace the `tar | tar` with a single `rsync`? `rsync -a root@hostname:/usr  /usr`. I won't comment on the wisdom of duplicating `/usr` between disparate systems. You should be able to set up rsync to use the same authentication as ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the data to a fifo, read the password from stdin:

```
trap 'rm -f /tmp/fifo' 0
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
ssh username@hostname 'cd /usr ; echo "password" |
     sudo -S tar cpf - . --ignore-failed-read' > /tmp/fifo & 
echo "${password?}" | sudo -S sh -c 'tar xpf - -C /usr < /tmp/fifo'
```